# shared_ptr std::dynamic_pointer_cast fails with "attempting to reference a deleted function" error

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, dynamic-cast

I have seen all the posts in StackOverflow regarding this similar error and still couldn't find what is causing issue in mine.

I'm using `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` to cast a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` object to a `std::shared_ptr<DerivedShared>` object, but I'm encountering a "attempting to reference a deleted function" error. I've ensured that the `Base` destructor is virtual but the error persists.

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Are there any known limitations or bugs in the standard library that could be contributing to this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S** : I know it works with `static_pointer_cast` but  wondering what is causing issue with **`dynamic_pointer_cast`**!

```
struct Base
{
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    //Copy
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = default;
    //Move
    Base(Base&&) = default;
    Base& operator=(Base&&) = default;
};


struct DerivedShared : public  Base
{
public:
    DerivedShared() //: data(std::shared_ptr<int[]>(new int[3]{1,2,3}))
    {
        //data = std::make_shared<int[]>(new int[3]{ 1,2,3 });
        data = std::shared_ptr<int[]>(new int[3]{ 1,2,3 });
    }
    
public:
    std::shared_ptr<int[]> data;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------\n";
    std::shared_ptr<Base> base5 = std::make_shared<DerivedShared>();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedShared>(base5)->data[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiles without error on all compilers I tested: https://godbolt.org/z/z7rKTaaKj

Comment: it is giving me the compile-time error!
Project Severity Code Description Line File Suppression State
SandBox Error C2280 'std::shared_ptr<DerivedShared> std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedShared,Base>(const std::shared_ptr<Base> &) noexcept': attempting to reference a deleted function .   

tried with C++ 14 till C++ 23 and doesn't work

Comment: You might have disabled RTTI in your compiler or some other build issues.

Comment: Project Severity Code Description Line File Suppression State
SandBox Error C2280 'std::shared_ptr<DerivedShared> std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedShared,Base>(const std::shared_ptr<Base> &) noexcept': attempting to reference a deleted function 103 C:\Preparing for interviews\Advanced C++\Virtual Destructor and Smart Destructor\SandBox\main.cpp 


That is the whole error message

Comment: I just found the following (there is message in VS when I clicked on it , i direct to the code below in memory.cpp)





#else // _CPPRTTI
template <class _Ty1, class _Ty2>
shared_ptr<_Ty1> dynamic_pointer_cast(const shared_ptr<_Ty2>&) noexcept = delete; // requires /GR option
template <class _Ty1, class _Ty2>
shared_ptr<_Ty1> dynamic_pointer_cast(shared_ptr<_Ty2>&&) noexcept = delete; // requires /GR option
#endif // _CPPRTTI

Comment: Yeah, that's the `#else` branch for when RTTI is disabled (https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/memory#L2049). You can't use `dynamic_cast` with RTTI disabled. The question is why you disabled it in the first place?

Comment: I didn't change it at all and had no idea what RTTI is but I am using a template VS from my prof's . I think he disabled it!!! i had been working on it for like 2 hours and read every similar posts regarding that issue in StackOverFlow :(

Comment: @Sam Then I'd suggest asking your Prof whether he disabled RTTI intentionally, if so why, and how you should work without it. By default it should be enabled as it is part of the standard C++ language and some core language features like `dynamic_cast` and `typeid` won't work without it. (Although it is often disabled e.g. in embedded development for various reasons.)

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks for your help. I  don't take any courses with him but I am still using his template because it has automatic memory leak detection framework that helps me to observe memory leaks especially when I am practicing and exploring C++ features. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You disabled RTTI and in this case Microsoft's implementation of the standard library defines `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` as deleted, since the `dynamic_cast` can't work without RTTI. (See https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/memory#L2049.)

You can't disable RTTI if you want to use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`.